# Django not rendering field in non model form

Tags: python, django, forms

I don't know what's happening here, could anybody help me?
I've some data I store as text (structured like a json). That text is created/edited with a formset embedded in a form (elements.html , element_form.html). That templates are used (and working) by RenderToResponse. All the requests are ajax POST, and the form is managed in a ModalForm.
All the fields are form.****Field, but I want to replace a not working ImageField (I dunno how to handle myself request.FILES with Ajax), so I was trying to use https://github.com/bradleyg/django-s3direct (I have my media in an s3 bucket), so now I have this field definition in my form:
image = S3DirectField()
but, I get this on my rendered form:
`<s3direct.fields.S3DirectField>`

There are no errors or traceback.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That project appears to only define a model field, not a form field.

It does however provide a form widget, `s3direct.widgets.S3DirectEditor`, which it uses in conjunction with a standard form text field. You can no doubt do the same.

Comment: That's right, I'm getting some errors, but widget is displayed. thanks!